# When using Access from within an Excel spreadsheet, the PC won't go to sleep

Tags: excel, hibernate, vba, networking, sleep

I've stumbled accross a problem I am unable to solve :(
Neither Google nor StackOverflow have given me any usable answers, so I'm turning to you.

The problem is this:
I've created a spreadsheet that loads data from an Access database stored on a network drive.
The data-loading part is only done once, i.e. when opening the file.

I open the connection like this:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set con = GetConString()
rs.Open "SELECT ID, somevalue FROM sometable", con
```

Where to connection string is something like this

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & (network path to file) & "'"
```

Then I dump the information in the spreadsheet and terminate the connection like this:

```
rs.Close
con.Close
```

However, when I try to hibernate the PC while this Excel spreadsheet is still open, I get an error message.
It translates to something along the lines of "Excel has prevented the computer from going to sleep".

This seems to happen only when using this constellation...
Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this behavior?
I'd like my PC to go to sleep, when I tell it to - even though the Excel spreadsheet is still open.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your Close lines you could

```
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
```

although I cannot guarantee that this is what is causing your computer to not hibernate - more information would be required.